# Show date details in EGit history

Tags: eclipse, config, egit, eclipse-kepler

Hi I just installed Kepler and started using EGit. In the history view, changes checked in in the past are showing as xx days/weeks/months ago. Instead of these notations, I want to see the datetime details (or best to have both along side each other).

How do you config EGit to do that?

If it is not possible in the current config, I dont mind compiling my own patched version of EGit, please provide where the line of code lies.

Thank you

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the History view:

1. Click on the view menu (the triangle button)
2. Deselect *Show* > *Relative Dates*

Alternatively, change it in the preferences:

1. Go to *Version Control (Team)* > *Git* > *History*
2. Deselect *Relative Dates*

Comment: Ah thank you! Too easy! But I reckon you can't show both date and relative date at the same time...

Comment: I think it would make sense to show the absolute date when hovering over the relative date as a tooltip. Could you please file an [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EGit&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All) against EGit? I can have a look at implementing it then.

Comment: @robinst The current version has the tooltip showing the absolute date. As of Eclipse Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)